# JSON - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I want take some JSON values and make variable from them, but when I do it I get an error.
In first stage JSON array is empty, thats why I used `if != null`, but even with filled array I get an error.

```
var tempJS=[];  
$("#sth td").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    tempJS.push({"COLOR":$this.attr("data-color"),});
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempJS));

if(tempJS!=null) var kolor=tempJS[c-1].COLOR;
```

Why is the last line giving me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'COLOR' of undefined

Comment: The error is very explicit, what is undefined is tempJS[c-1], where is that "c" on the code?, beside you are checking that tempJS is not null, it assigning tempJS[c-1], you should check for the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try on the console:

```
[]==null
> false
```

you'll see that returns `false`. This means that if you check if the array equals `null` you will always get a false, and always run the code in the `if` statement.

You should do this instead:

```
if(tempJS.length) var kolor=tempJS[c-1].COLOR;
```

You don't need `if(tempJS.length > 0)` because every number is treated like `true` except `0` that means `false`.

Comment: I was tottaly searching bug in JSON values... And it was array null/empty mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A zero-length array is not same as null. Try testing `if (tempJS.length > 0) ...`